# Create nested HTML div elements using JavaScript (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Any idea How can I create the following div structure using JavaScript or JQuery, then i would like to append this structure to a div with a class = "grid"

```
<div class="grid-item grid-item--width">
 <div class="card">
   <div class="card-body">
      <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-between">
        <div>
           <p class="h5">User Name</p>
           <p class="h5">Level</p>
        </div>
        <div>
           <p class="h5">Category</p>
        </div>
     </div>
    <img class="card-img-bottom" src="hands.jpg"
    alt="Card image cap" style="width:344px">
    <p class="card-text">This is a wider card</p>
    <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-between">
       <div>
         <p class="h5">Location</p>
       </div>
       <div>
         <p class="h5">Life Time</p>
       </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure JS is the fastest way, just create a string from all required html code and append it to innerHTML of the element you want, see snippet:

```js
var divend = '</div>';
var divstart = '<div>';
var pclass5 = '<p class="h5">';
var pend = '</p>'

var grid_item = '<div class="grid-item grid-item--width"><div class="card"><div class="card-body">'+
 '<div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-between">' + divstart+ pclass5+'User Name'+pend+ pclass5+
 'Level'+pend+ divend+ divstart+ pclass5+'Category'+pend + divend + divend+
    '<img class="card-img-bottom" src="hands.jpg" alt="Card image cap" style="width:344px">'+
    '<p class="card-text">' + 'This is a wider card'+ pend+  '<div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-between">'+  divstart+  pclass5+'Location'+pend+  divend+ divstart+
         pclass5+'Life Time'+pend+ divend+  divend+ divend+ divend+ divend;
   

 var grids = document.getElementsByClassName('grid');
// add for all elements with class == grid
 [...grids].forEach(grid=>{grid.innerHTML += grid_item;});
```

```html
<div class='grid'></div>
```

P.s. if you have a lot of elements with class name grid, instead of `forEach`, use a normal `for(){}` loop, it is about twice faster performance wise depending on the browser.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery .append() and his family  [ appendTo(), .prepend() ] is your friends.

```
var
new_HTML_cod = "<div class=\"grid-item grid-item--width\">";
new_HTML_cod += " <div class=\"card\">";
new_HTML_cod += "  <div class=\"card-body\">";
//...
$(new_HTML_cod).appendTo($('.grid'));
```